# creating an ios and Android app

Tags: android, ios

I am looking into creating an IOS/Android app although I am not sure how I should go about doing it.
 if its better to make them in 2 separate environments( meaning Android Studio for one and Visual Studio for another).

Or I looked online and found Xamirin for studio which says you can make one app compatiable for both devices. I also heard from a select few that Xamirin has issues.

What would be the better route and is there a program I could use to do both?

Comment: Please add some more info about the requirements of the app. Generally speaking from my experience it becomes more challenging using a cross-platform development framework when the app requires OS specific functionality such as multimedia processing or 3rd party integration i.e. acoustic fingerprinting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the nature of the app and your coding skills. If the app requires 'pixel-perfect' UI, has a lot of customization and complex design then you should go for native development. The best starting points for native development are [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/) and [Android](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html) official documentation and training guides.

If your app is relatively simpler especially in term of UI then you can consider cross-platform development. In cross-platform development, you usually have a single code base and you can generate apps both for Android and iOS. [NativeScript](https://docs.nativescript.org/tutorial/ng-chapter-0), [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) and [Xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/) are good cross-platform development options.

Answer (score 0):

Pick one and focus on it.  Don't try doing more than you can handle.  I suggest ios because you will probably make more money. If the app takes off then start worrying about making a Android version.

Comment: ok thanks I actually have made  an android app before its ios thatt I am not so familiar with. I just thought I read online that there was a way to make both in one program vs having to do it separate.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Ionic 2 http://ionic.io/2 or React Native https://facebook.github.io/react-native/

Answer (score 0):

There are various cross-platform development tools: Xamarin, Ionic, React Native, Appcelerator, etc.

I've worked with cross-platform tools in the past. They tend to be cumbersome and put you at a remove from the native OS. I'm not a fan, but now we're straying into the realm of opinions.